# How/when does one use "a most"?

Tags: superlative-degree

I've recently come across a novel called [A most wanted man](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Most_Wanted_Man), after which being curious I found a TV episode called [A most unusual camera](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Most_Unusual_Camera).

Could someone shed some light on how to use "a most" and whether it has anything to do with "the most"?

Answer (score 8):

"Most" in this context means "very." As in "a very wanted man." It functions as a "superlative."

This usage is considered "dated" and is not recommended for modern contexts. I am providing this explanation for people who want to read (or possibly write) earlier "period" novels or shows.

Comment: I think it's a somewhat dated/quaint usage. There's Paul Simon's 1965 song [A Most Peculiar Man](http://www.lyricsfreak.com/s/simon+and+garfunkel/a+most+peculiar+man_20124714.html), and John le Carré's spy novel mentioned by OP. But the best advice to anyone unfamiliar with the form is probably just to read *most* as *very*, and avoid actually using it at all.

Comment: I agree that the usage is dated; it sounds precious or pompous in a modern context.

Comment: +1. It can also mean "almost", which is also somewhat dated/quaint.

Comment: @ruakh - Yes, the distinction between "almost" and "very" is easily made from the context, if one is a native English speaker, but could certainly be ambiguous to someone who is less familiar with the language.

Answer (score 4):

This is a special kind of absolute superlative.  The OED gives as its sense 2 of ***most*** *adv.* the following:

> As an intensive superlative qualifying adjs. and advs.: In the greatest possible degree.  
> <sub>For the ceremonial titles, Most Christian, Most Honourable, Most Noble, Most Reverend, etc., see those adjs.</sub>

I don’t think it gets used all that very much anymore.  One of the examples is:

> 1710 Hearne *Collect*. (O.H.S.) II. 351 ― A most vile, stinking Whigg.

Comment: I agree it's not used all that much any more.

Answer (score 0):

Most can be used as ['very'](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/most)... so 'a most' means 'a very'......

> adv. Superlative of much; (intensifier):  very. e.g. a *most* impressive piece of writing. (TFD/AHDEL)

Comment: This answer has already been given.

Answer (score 0):

Generally the definite Article **'the'** is placed before any superlative. But there  is an exception to this rule. This special use of ***'superlative' is called 'absolute superlative' or 'superlative of eminence'***.

**Positive, comparative, and superlative** degrees are used for **comparison**. But ***'absolute superlative' or 'superlative of eminence'***, are used **to express a very great degree of a quality, with no idea of comparison**.

Consider:

1. A most beautiful sight...
2. A most interesting book...
3. He met me in a politest manner.

Comment: To me #3 sounds bogus.  It may technically be "legal", but it doesn't go down smoothly at all.

Answer (score 0):

The question is misleading. Instead of asking for the meaning of "A most", it would be better to ask for the meaning of "most wanted":

```
A most wanted man
```

is to be read:

```
A [most wanted] man
```

and turns out to be:

```
A man who is most wanted
```

Comment: I don't think I agree, but supposing for the sake of argument that you're right . . . what is the meaning of "most wanted"? This answer, as written, seems incomplete.